# differentiate undefined and null in Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

Consider the following function:

```
 BasicClass copyWith({
    String id,
  }) {
   // some code behaving differently for 1) id is undefined and 2) id is explicit null
  }
```

And consider the two parameters below:

1. Nothing (id is undefined)

   copyWith();
2. Null (id is null)

   copyWith(id: null);

in the copyWith method, is there any way I can make it behave differently for 1) and 2)

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/877

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no way to differentiate `null` from "no parameter passed".

The only workaround (which is used by [Freezed](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed) to generate a copyWith that supports `null`) is to cheat using a custom default value:

```dart
final undefined = Object();

class Example {
  Example({this.param});
  final String param;

  Example copyWith({Object param = undefined}) {
    return Example(
      param: param == undefined ? this.param : param as String,
    );
  }
}
```

This requires typing your variables as `Object` though.

To fix that issue, you can use inheritance to hide the `Object` under a type-safe interface (again, see [Freezed](https://github.com/rrousselGit/freezed)):

```dart
final undefined = Object();

class Example {
  Example._();
  factory Example({String param}) = _Example;
  
  String get param;

  void method() {
    print('$param');
  }

  Example copyWith({String param});
}

class _Example extends Example {
  _Example({this.param}): super._();

  final String param;

  @override
  Example copyWith({Object param = undefined}) {
    return Example(
      param: param == undefined ? this.param : param as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This is such a hack for something as simple `undefined  !==null  // true` ( in js )

Comment: Dartz also has a Unit type, which is considered non-null no value passed.  I cannot remember how exactly it works.  You'll just to look it up.  Dart is still very new and hasn't caught up to some basic features that older languages have.

Comment: @TSR You think it'd be simple to add, but even small language changes can have significant ramifications and need to be carefully considered, especially since changes aren't easy to undo.

Comment: `undefined` caused a lot of frustration in the JS world and wasn't added to Dart on purpose. Cloning object is likely to be a separate language feature, like the spread operator.

Comment: We should extends the `null` object to carry information `isImplicit` . This boolean is `true` by default for any variable declared with no value and when no parameters is passed, this is `false` when the value is set to null explicitly. To read it, we can add a built-in function like : `bool isImplicitNull(myVar)` or some new syntax. This will save a lot of boilerplate and crazy hacks like this (and no need for the famously confusing `undefined` of JS)